# Get user XML response to richTextBox in client app

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, client

I am invoking a web service function which is reading a users credentials from a database,

when invoked straight from the web service based on entering a 'search' integer, the response is -

```
<firstName>john</firstName>
<lastName>smith</lastName>
<sex>male</sex>
<age>23</age>
<search>100</search>
```

I am trying to get the results back to the client in a richTextBox I thought by doing this-

```
        WebService.Service1SoapClient client = new WebService.Service1SoapClient();
        int search= System.Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
        string result = client.searchUser(search);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(result);
```

However this is not working.

Comment: What's the error and on which line?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type'WebService.downloadUser' to 'string' which is a struct in the webservice that creates an array[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments,

```
string result = client.searchUser(search);
```

you are trying to assign at structure to a string. That's the error and compiler is telling you that you can't do this.

You should `override` `ToString()` method in your structure like,

```
public override string ToString()
{
   // construct the string here which you want to assign
}
```

and at your client side

```
string result = client.searchUser(search).ToString();
```

Hopefully it will help.